З чого це у третьому чотиривірші миски полетіли до порога?
Не можу зрозуміти причинного зв'язку в третьому чотиривірші. Чому миски/тарілки почали летіти до порога?

Ой, на горі жовта бляха,
Полюбила дівка ляха,
Не так ляха, як Данила,
Бо в Данила душа мила!
Чоловіче-макогоне,
Пусти мене на поклони!
Як я, жінко, макогін,
Сиди в дома без поклін!
Чоловіче, бійся Бога,
Летять миски до порога,
Не так миски, як тарілки,
За чужії краще жінки.
Чоловіче, схаменися,
Сиди вдома, не казися,
Бо за чужі краще жінки
Нема миски, ні тарілки!

youtube

Я так розумію що чоловік каже "чужі жінки краще", за що жінка кидає в нього миски і тарілки. Чому "до порога" - мабуть тому що чоловік від цього тікає у двері?

@Artemix теж думав про це, може це просто закінчення такі незвичайні
